# How can I play Plants vs. Zombies in full screen mode?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

How can I play Plants vs. Zombies in full screen mode? I usually play this game on http://www.zombiegames.co/play/plants-vs-zombies but this is not full version of the game.

Comment: You could also try to use a packet-sniffer to download the Flash file (and the other files it downloads, then run it with the Adobe Flash Projector), but you might have to run a local web-server to spoof the domain. It can be done, but would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your browser in full-screen mode (On Firefox this is `F11`) and instead of navigating to that page, go directly to the `.swf` file:

http://www.popcap.com/sites/www.popcap.com/prettypkg/games/pvz/flash/1033/pvz_9_15.swf

It's not quite fullscreen, but it's close.

You could also download the demo version through Steam. On the [**Plants Vs Zombies page**](http://store.steampowered.com/app/3590/?snr=1_7_15__13), in the right-side column, there is a button labelled "**Download PC Demo**":

[image: PvZ 'Download PC Demo' Button]

Of course, if you have some cash to spend, the full version of Plants vs Zombies is only $4.99 USD (same Steam page).

Comment: *"It's not quite fullscreen, but it's close."*   What do you mean? I just tried it in Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Opera, and it was fullscreen in all of them.

Comment: @Synetech - when I tried this, Firefox left a bar along the top for some reason

Comment: Yes, Firefox seems to be a bit wonky when it comes to switching to fullscreen and auto-hiding the toolbar. You can switch out of fullscreen mode (using the mouse since the Flash player has captured the keyboard, so `F11` won’t work), then switch back (again, using the mouse to select *View ⇨ Full Screen* since the Flash captures `F11`). Just make sure to move the cursor away from the top of the screen quickly, and while playing, don’t move the cursor near the top otherwise it will show it again and not auto-hide it.